# VSTO 2015 generates pseudo code depending on office installed language

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, culture

On my workstation, I created, using VSTO 2015, a project with the template named 'Excel 2013 and 2016 VSTO Workbook'.
I used the Copy option from the project template to copy an existing Excel document.
I have Office 2016 in french installed on this computer, and VS generated a code with several classes inheriting from WorksheetBase with names 'Feuill1', Feuill2', etc. For the sheet n, the cookies and identifier parameters for the WorksheetBase constructor are generated in code as 'Feuilln',"Feuilln'.
I adapted my code and the project runs perfectly.
I then copied my VS project to another computer where Office 2016 was installed for english language. When I try to run my project I get errors, it appears that Feuilln is not found. I changed these names for 'Sheetn' and it worked.
I am very disapointed : isn't it a misconception to generate classes depending on the culture ???
Is there a way to create a project working independently of Office culture ?

I can't find any documentation on the process used by the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Factory and its usage of the xxxx.Designer.xml parameter file. Is adapting this file the way to go to be culture independant ?